# An uncountable set has uncountably many co-countable subsets containing an arbitrary point

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

This theorem seems "obvious" to me, but I want to check my logic since I am un-familiar with un-countably infinite sets, and I know these can give rise to non-intuitive results. Any comments welcome.

**Definitions**

The cardinality of a set $A$ will be denoted $|A|$. If $|A|=|\mathbb{N}|$, $A$ will be called *countable* or *countably infinite* and this will be denoted $|A|=\aleph_{0}$. If $A$ is infinite and $|A|\ne\aleph_{0}$, $A$ will be called *uncountable* or *uncountably infinite*.

**Claim**

If $A$ is un-countable then for any $a\in A$, $A$ contains an uncountable number of disjoint co-countable sets that contain $a$. More formally;

> For any $a\in A$ where $|A|\not=\aleph_{0}$ there exist subsets
>   $B_{\beta}\subset A$, $\beta\in I_{\beta}$ for an index set
>   $I_{\beta}$, $|I_{\beta}|\not=\aleph_{0}$, such that for all $\beta\in I_{\beta}$
>   : $a\in B_{\beta}$  and $|A-B_{\beta}|=\aleph_{0}$.
>   Furthermore for any $\beta\not=\beta'$, $B_{\beta}\cap B_{\beta'}=\emptyset$

**Proof**

Without loss of generality let $I_{\beta}=\mathbb{R}$ and choose $\beta\in I_{\beta}$. Choose $a_{\beta,1}\in A$, $a_{\beta,1}\not=a$. Since $|A-\{a_{\beta,1}\}|\not=\aleph_{0}$ there exists $a_{\beta,2}\in\{A-\{a_{\beta,1}\}\}$, $a_{\beta,2}\not=a$. Since $|A-\{a_{\beta,1},a_{\beta,2}\}|\not=\aleph_{0}$ there exists $a_{\beta,3}\in\{A-\{a_{\beta,1},a_{\beta,2}\}\}$, $a_{\beta,3}\not=a$. Continuing in this way $n_{\beta}$ times, $n_{\beta}\in\mathbb{N}$, we can construct a set $B_{\beta}=A-\{a_{\beta,1},a_{\beta,2},...,a_{\beta,n_{\beta}}\}$ that satisfies $a\in B_{\beta}\subset A$ and $|A-B_{\beta}|=|\{a_{\beta,1},a_{\beta,2},...,a_{\beta,n_{\beta}}\}|=\aleph_{0}$ so that $B_{\beta}$ is a co-countable subset of $A$ containing $a$.

Choose another $\beta'\in I_{\beta}$, $\beta\not=\beta'$. Since $|B_{\beta}|\not=\aleph_{0}$ there exists $a_{\beta',1}\in B_{\beta}$, $a_{\beta',1}\not=a$. Since $|B_{\beta}-\{a_{\beta',1}\}|\not=\aleph_{0}$ there exists $a_{\beta',2}\in B_{\beta}-\{a_{\beta',1}\}$, $a_{\beta',2}\not=a$. Since $|B_{\beta}-\{a_{\beta',1},a_{\beta',2}\}|\not=\aleph_{0}$ there exists $a_{\beta',3}\in B_{\beta}-\{a_{\beta',1},a_{\beta',2}\}$, $a_{\beta',3}\not=a$. Continuing in this way $n_{\beta'}$ times, $n_{\beta'}\in\mathbb{N}$, we can construct a set $B_{\beta'}=B_{\beta}-\{a_{\beta',1},a_{\beta',2},...,a_{\beta',n_{\beta'}}\}$ that satisfies $a\in B_{\beta'}\subset A$ and $|A-B_{\beta'}|=|\{a_{\beta,1},a_{\beta,2},...,a_{\beta,n_{\beta}}\}\cup\{a_{\beta,1},a_{\beta,2},...,a_{\beta',n_{\beta'}}\}|=\aleph_{0}+\aleph_{0}=\aleph_{0}$ so that $B_{\beta'}$ is a co-countable subset of $A$ containing $a$.

Since $B_{\beta}\cap B_{\beta'}=\emptyset$ and since we can choose un-countably many $\beta\in I_{\beta}$ the result is proved $\hspace{5pt}\blacksquare$

Comment: Your definition of "uncountably infinite" is not standard. Usually, it is an infinite set $S$ such that $|S|\neq \aleph_0.$ There are a lot of uncountably infinite cardinals other than $|\mathbb R.|$

Comment: Many thanks Thomas - that basic fact had eluded me! I have amended notation accordingly - I believe my logic still stands as per the original question.

Comment: Do you know that every infinite set $S$ contains a countably infinite subset? And if and the set $\{T\subseteq \mathbb N\mid T\text{ is infinite}\}$ is uncountably infinite?

Comment: The claim is false. If a set is cocountable, its complement is countable, and cannot contain an uncountable set, much less a cocountable one.

Comment: No, you are wrong, @AndrésE.Caicedo Given $a\in A$ take a countable subset $C\subseteq A$ with $a\not\in C.$ Then take $\{A\setminus T\mid T\subset C, \text{ and T infinite}\}$. There are uncountably many (countably) infinite subsets $T$ of $C$, and for each $a\in A-T,$ and $A-T$ is co-countable.

Comment: @Thomas These sets are not disjoint.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Whoops. missed the disjoint. Entirely correct, this problem's claim is false.

Comment: Indeed, given two co-countable subsets, $A,B\subset S$ where $S$ is uncountable, we alway have $A\cap B\neq \emptyset.$ If $A=S\setminus A_1,B=S\setminus B_1$ where $A_1,B_1$ are countable, then $A\cap B=S\setminus (A_1\cup B_1)$

Comment: So if $A\cap B=\emptyset$ then $A_1\cup B_1=S,$ and thus $S$ is the union of two  countable sets, and hence $S$ is countable.

Comment: Thank you both for very useful comments. So the disjoint claim is cleary wrong (me not thinking this through fully), I can see that now. But removing this the claim is true ?: every uncountable set contains an uncountable number of co-countable subsets containing an arbitrary point?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo your first comment: Let $B=A-C$ for $|A|\not=\aleph_{0}$, $B\subset A$, $C\subset A$, $|C|=\aleph_{0}$ so that $|A-B|=|C|=\aleph_{0}$ giving that $B$ is co-countable. For arbitrary $a\in B$ we can construct $B_{1}=B-\{b_{1},b_{2},b_{3}\}$ say for $a\not=b_{j}$, $j=1,2,3$, such that $A-B_{1}=C\cup \{b_{1},b_{2},b_{3}\}$. Since $|A-B_{1}|=|C|+|\{b_{1},b_{2},b_{3}\}|=\aleph_{0}+\aleph_{0}=\aleph_{0}$ and $B_{1}\subset B\subset A$, we have that $B_{1}$ is a co-countable subset of $B$ containing $a$ - i.e the original claim involves $B$ containing the uncountable subset not $A-B$

Comment: @dandar Sorry, there is too much noise in your reply. Are you agreeing with what I wrote, asking how to prove it, asking what its relevance is to disproving the false claim, or what?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thanks for replying. Sorry I will try and be clearer: in your first comment you argue (correctly) that co-countable sets, by construction having complements that are countable, cannot contain an uncountable subset. You conclude my claim is incorrect as a result? My previous comment was to show that my original claim holds for all uncountable sets, even co-countable ones. My apologies if I have mis-understood your comments. Thus aside from the erroneous disjoint claim, my claim is correct?

Comment: @dandar Without the requirement of disjointness, of course the claim holds, and it is straightforward. Thomas sketched in comments what to do. I do not see uncountably many sets produced using procedures along the lines your comment suggests. If besides disjointness we also ignore the requirement of having uncountably many such sets, then yes, your comment gives a possible approach.

Comment: Thank you again @AndrésE.Caicedo. So from Thomas' second comment; 
Let $|A|\not=\aleph_{0}$ and choose $a\in A$. We can take $C\subseteq A$ such that $a\in C$ and $|C|=\aleph_{0}$. There exist $T_{\beta}\subset C$, $\beta\in I_{\beta}$ for index set satisfying $|I_{\beta}|\not=\aleph_{0}$ such that $|T_{\beta}|=\aleph_{0}$ for all $\beta$. The sets $B_{\beta}:=A-T_{\beta}$ have complements $A-B_{\beta}=T_{\beta}\subset C$ so that $|A-B_{\beta}|=\aleph_{0}$. Thus the sets $\{B_{\beta}\}_{\beta\in I_{\beta}}$ are an uncountable collection of co-countable subsets of $A$ containing the point $a$.

Comment: @dandar Yes, that's the argument.